# Explicit Bezier Curves: Lerping between curves same as lerping control points?

Tags: interpolation, bezier-curve

Let's say that you have two explicit (one dimensional) quadratic Bezier curves:

$f(t) = A(1-t)^2+B(1-t)t+Ct^2$
$g(t) = D(1-t)^2+E(1-t)t+Ft^2$

Where $A, B, C, D, E, F$ are scalar constants.

Then, let's say that you evaluate $f$ and $g$ for some value $t$ and linearly interpolate between those two values by some amount $u$.

Is the result you get always going to be the same as if you evaluated the function below?

$h(t) = G(1-t)^2+H(1-t)t+It^2$

Where

$G = A(1-u) + D(u)$
$H = B(1-u) + E(u)$
$I = C(1-u) + F(u)$

In other words... is lerping between the same time $t$ point on two curves always the same as if you lerped the control points, then evaluated the resulting curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be. To see this, just compute the linear interpolation explicitly, and then gather up all the terms that correspond to each of $(1-t)^2$, $t(1-t)$, and $t^2$. You'll find that they're precisely the $G$, $H$, and $I$ you've defined.

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that $f$ is linear in $A$, $B$, and $C$, and similarly for $g$.

Comment: Do you guys know if there are any other interesting operations that can be  done on the result of a curve evaluation that are equivelant to the operation being done on the control points (or a similar operation done)?  It could be a unary operation, or N-way operation.  Things like scaling, projection, rotation, lerping (which apparently works!) etc.  I asked here but no answers or comments yet: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294946/equivalent-operations-on-bezier-curve-points-as-control-points